# How to store ipv4 and ipv6 addresses in postgresql using GORM

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, ip-address, go-gorm

How do we insert and select from a table with inet datatype for ip addresses using [GORM](https://gorm.io/docs/) with postgresql?

here is my model

```
import (
    "github.com/jackc/pgtype"
)

...
ClientIp     pgtype.Inet `json:"client_ip" gorm:"type:inet;not null"`
...
```

I am trying to parse the ip address which is in string format to type `pgtype.Inet` in postgresql database
like this when inserting into the database

```
import (
    "net"
)

...
ClientIp:     net.ParseIP(c.IP()),
...
```

we are told to [parse the ip using `net` package](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/inet.go#L52) but this is error from that

```
cannot use net.ParseIP(c.IP()) (type net.IP) as type pgtype.Inet in field value
```

I have also tried using `net` package for the model

```
import (
    "net"
)

...
ClientIp     net.IP `json:"client_ip" gorm:"type:inet;not null"`
...
```

but kept getting this error

```
sql: Scan error on column index 16, name "client_ip": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type string into type *net.IP
```

so **how do we store `inet` values inside postgresql using GORM?**

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/914) help? (That `pgtype.Inet` hints you're using `sqlx`, wich you did not mention.) Also see [this](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/inet.go#L141).

Comment: no using gorm as it was mentioned here also https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3150

Comment: do i need to import another package? i see this https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/914 but not sure what i need to add/remove to have it work with gorm

Comment: @kostix updated question with more details of packages am using. Please let me know if i need to add any more packages. thanks

Comment: I don't quite get your problem. I glanced at the source code of `pgtype.Inet` and it happily accepts string form of IP addresses in its `Set` method, so here we go: <https://go.dev/play/p/cGY1HugU92z>. Is this what you're looking for or not?

Comment: ok i just ran the code and what are the `<nil>` and `2` at the end? also i do not want the subnet in the ips, i just want single ip not network address `127.0.0.1 <nil> {127.0.0.1/32 2}
192.168.2.152 <nil> {192.168.2.152/32 2}
::1 <nil> {::1/128 2}
2a00:1450:4026:804::2004 <nil> {2a00:1450:4026:804::2004/128 2}`

Comment: Let me leave the first question as a homework exercise. Sorry for being a bit harsh and dismissive but if you cannot make this out from the code on yourself, I'm afraid dealing with the problem we're dealing with here is a bit premature endaevor. As to the second question—I don't know for sure because you have provided sort of zero information on it, but I guess that's because the underlying field in your PostgreSQL server has type `inet` or `cidr`, and it includes a netmask as documented <https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html>.

Comment: Regarding the netmask, I'm not sure it can cause any harm: as you can see in my example, I've used only bare IP addresses and all of them got parsed with "all ones" netmask—/32 for IPv4 and /128 for IPv6,—which basically means that all bits there are the address of a host. So, does it really impedes what you're after or it's just premature fears?

Comment: «provided sort of zero information on it»—sorry, my bad: there's the necessary bit: the struct tag `gorm:"type:inet;not null"` which clearly lists the PostgreSQL's type of the underlying column, and it's `inet`.

Comment: output is from your golang playground code, also not sure what information i have not provided. i have explained what i am having issues with and what i have tried..what information do you need?

Comment: OK, have fun, cheers.

Comment: i came here for help not to be given an exercise or not be clear with your comment. are you here to help or take jab at people? if i knew the answer i wouldnt post question here..maybe see how others answer questions and see how helpful they are. even after trying what you have which again doesnt work for me `cannot use ip.Set(c.IP()) (type error) as type pgtype.Inet in field value`

Comment: Have you tried to actually read the source code of `pgtype.Inet.Set`? What does it return? Do you understand how it works? I mean, being a volunteer on SO (which, yes, is a resource where you get unpaid help), I'm only willing to help with interesing tasks and not tutoring on the very basics of a particular language or read the readily available source code for you. This is not interesting to me, and as with any unpaid help, it's "take it or leave it" thing. You think I failed to help? I beg to disagree but otherwise it's fine: if you don't want to lift a finger to help yourself, let be it.

Answer (score 2):

model :

```golang
import (
    "github.com/jackc/pgtype"
)

...
ClientIp     pgtype.Inet `json:"client_ip" gorm:"type:inet;not null"`
...
```

then you can create func `SetInet` like this

```golang
func SetInet(ip string) pgtype.Inet {
    var inet pgtype.Inet
    inet.Set(ip)
    return inet
}
```

then you can use that function to set inet :

```golang
...
ClientIp:     SetInet("127.0.0.1"),
...
```

**If you don't want to create func** like that you can set it from variable that contain field `pgtype.Inet`

example :

```
...
    type Ip struct {
        gorm.Model
        ClientIp pgtype.Inet `gorm:"type:inet;not null"`
    }
...
    var ip Ip

    ip.ClientIp.Set("127.0.0.1")
...
```

Comment: I have to do all these to store ip addresses? wow...appreciate your help. Will test this soon and let you know how it goes

Comment: its a bit more difficult to test your answer as you added a lot more than just storing and retrieving ip in database, i already have struct model and database, all i need is just the column to store ip address; still trying to piece out what i need from your answer. will great to make answer stick to original code from question to keep things easy

Comment: @uberrebu I have updated my answer to just store ip address with inet type

Comment: do i keep the model for the column same like this? `ClientIp     pgtype.Inet `json:"client_ip" gorm:"type:inet;not null"``? or what datatype do i use for the model column `ClientIp`?

Comment: do i need a function for this? couldn't i just parse within the struct to insert the ip into the database? I decided to store the ip as a string and then when i need to to, will convert to inet. But will still test this to see if it works

Comment: I decided to store ips as string and just convert whenever i need to; i created this question so i dont waste too much time but i ended up wasting lots of time on this as no one would provide any help and i kept wasting days on days; so i decided to use string and keep my sanity

Comment: It was answered by kostix, and I'm just show you examples